# How to add @mention user name or groups feature in a text area of lwc component in salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, search

I have a simple form with a text area in which when user types '@' I need to auto suggest user names/groups. How I can achieve it using LWC in salesforce?

Comment: You can probably use editor libraries like cke  and develop your own extensions.

Comment: is it not available within salesforce's lwc by default?

Comment: @-mentioning users is a feature of Chatter. It is not available in generic text fields. You would have to implement this from the ground up, or figure out a way to use Chatter instead of a custom form.

Comment: I’m looking into the same thing, did you find any solution to this ?